# index out of range but is in fact in range

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, range

I am having an issue with a list that I have split from some text by using the comma delimiter.

The list has 4-5 items but when I try to get the 4th-5th item in the list, it says out of range. Not sure why it's happening.

```
import re
import requests
r = requests.get('https://halalhmc.org/outlets-by-name/')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'outlet-content'})

records = []
for result in results:

    name = result.find('h3').text
    fullAddress = result.find('p', attrs={'class':'outlet-address'}).text
    split_address = fullAddress.split(',')
    address1 = split_address[0]
    city = split_address[1]
    city1 = split_address[2]
    validPcode = re.match("[A-Z]{2}[0-9] [0-9][A-Z]{2}",split_address[3])
    if validPcode:
        postCode = split_address[3]
    else:
        county = split_address[3]
        postCode = split_address[4]
    records.append((name,address1[10:],city,city1,postCode))

print records[2]
```

When I do print `len(split_address)` and remove `print records[1]`, I get 5 as the length.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the full error traceback?

Comment: the html code maybe useful

Comment: One thing we can be sure of is that it *is* in fact out or range, I suggest you add some print statements to allow you to to debug your code like `print(split_address)` and `print(len(split_address))`

Comment: @DavidG The error is 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HMC.py", line 24, in <module>
    postCode = split_address[4]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Dominique Thanks for your insight. Firstly, I am a newbie just learning how to code in python. Secondly, I spent the whole night yesterday and morning today to debug the issue by googling and trying various things. Thirdly, why are some on StackOverflow so harsh? Isn't this a place to ask questions and get help?

Comment: @Chris_Rands When I do `print len(split_address)` and remove `print records[1]`, I get 5 as the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try to debug your code by yourself first. Anyhow for your question **Why is this happening? :**

It gives you error in `postCode = split_address[4]` because your list has 4 elements 0,1,2,3 and you are accessing the 4th element which is not present..
[image]

you don't have the `index[4]` thats why it gives you error out of range!

**Updated Area:**

In your for loop the length of `split_address` is changing to 4 and 5 and when the length is 4 and your are trying to get `index[4]` it will give definitely gives you error of index out of range to solve this issue you have to add a check on it.

**Try this:**

```
import re
import requests
r = requests.get('https://halalhmc.org/outlets-by-name/')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'outlet-content'})

records = []
for result in results:

    name = result.find('h3').text
    fullAddress = (result.find('p', attrs={'class':'outlet-address'})).text
    split_address = fullAddress.split(',')
    address1 = split_address[0]
    city = split_address[1]
    city1 = split_address[2]
    validPcode = re.match("[A-Z]{2}[0-9] [0-9][A-Z]{2}",split_address[3])
    if validPcode:
        postCode = split_address[3]
    else:
        county = split_address[3]
        if len(split_address) is 4:
            postCode = split_address[3]
        elif len(split_address) is 3:
            postCode = split_address[4]
    records.append((name,address1[10:],city,city1,postCode))

# only for checking
print records[1]
print records[2]
print records[3]
print records[4]
print records[5]
```

i have modified your code little bit and only adds one check on it(`split_address`).

Hope you will understand and it will help you! :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In this instance it is such that it is not present but when I try to run the same code for another record which does have the 5th item, it still doesn't work. try `print records[1]`

Comment: @Muhammadibn : check the updated answer! Hope it will help you! :) Moreover, i think you have to split your country to. to get the postal code!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did do the `re.match` but didn't do the `else` statements correctly. I understand it now.